# How to read a session variable in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to read a session variable value in aspx, but the code behind don´t work.

```
<div class="row">
   E-mail:&nbsp;<%# HttpContext.Current.Session["email"].ToString() %>
</div>
```

Please help me. I know how to do this in .cs file, but i need to read directly in .aspx. Thanks!

Comment: Define `don't work`. Also please us the code where you **write** to the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
E-mail:&nbsp;<% Response.Write((string)(HttpContext.Current.Session["email"])); %>
```